# Adding tables results in nested tables

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I am attempting to add consecutive tables to a word document from C# (VS 2013, .NET 4.5, Word 2013) and the code below nests the second table within the first table.  I am attempting to create distinct tables that are added between two bookmarks (I have tested this with a range defined as a single bookmark as well).

I own the code and source/destination document format, so i can make any changes as needed, however the content is all dynamic, so i can't just create a pre-defined bookmark for each table.

A subset of the code that is representative of my issue is below:

```
Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
Word.Document oTargetWordDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(WordTemplateFile);

object oBookmarkBegin = "bookmark_begin";
object oBookmarkEnd = "bookmark_end";

object oBookmarkBeginRange = oTargetWordDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookmarkBegin).Range.Start;
object oBookmarkEndRange = oTargetWordDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookmarkEnd).Range.Start;

Word.Range oRange = oTargetWordDoc.Range(ref oBookmarkBeginRange, ref oBookmarkEndRange);

Word.Table wtTable1 = oRange.Tables.Add(oRange, 1, 2);
wtTable1.Cell(1,1).Range.Text = "t1/r1/c1";
wtTable1.Cell(1,2).Range.Text = "t1/r1/c2";

Word.Table wtTable2 = oRange.Tables.Add(oRange, 1, 2);
wtTable2.Cell(1,1).Range.Text = "t2/r1/c1";
wtTable2.Cell(1,2).Range.Text = "t2/r1/c2";

// other goo/close/save/etc...
```

The output looks like this:

```
t1/r1/c1|t1/r1/c2
t2/r1/c1|t2/r1/c2| <-- nested within column 1 in the first table (notice trailing | marking beginning of first table's second column)
```

Clearly, I would like two distinct tables, without nesting, resulting in:

```
t1/r1/c1|t1/r1/c2
t2/r1/c1|t2/r1/c2
```

Any assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated!